# Cannot Set Figure DPI

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set the figure DPI. The docs say that it *should* default to 100, but it is defaulting to 200. I am trying to force it to 200 in 2 different ways. No dice.

Here is my python script in its entirety.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 100
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1, 1), dpi=100)
print(fig.dpi) # prints 200
```

Why is the figure's DPI 200?

Comment: Maybe it depends on the environment where you run your code and the backend in use?

Comment: When I run from Jupyter labs, it behaves as expected (100 dpi). When I run the script from the terminal, it behaves as described above. How would I dig deeper? Any suggestions on where to check?